# not able to Invert bitand value using bitnot, e.g from 1 to 0 in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, bitwise-operators, ddl

Creating a virtual column whose value is computed using other 3 columns -

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
  id          NUMBER,
  comm1       number,
  comm2       number,
  comm3       number,
  comm4        number GENERATED ALWAYS AS
                
((comm1 - bitand(comm1, comm2) + comm2) - bitand((comm1 - bitand(comm1, comm2) + comm2),comm3)+comm3)  VIRTUAL,
              
  CONSTRAINT employees_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

if i insert-

```
INSERT INTO emp (id,comm1, comm2,comm3)
VALUES (3, 1,1,1);
```

**Column comm4 get value of 1, i want 0**
how can i invert it.

Comment: Are the values in your `comm1`, `comm2` and `comm3` columns only ever going to be 0 or 1, or can they be larger?

Answer (score 1):

We can invert 0 to 1 and 1 to 0 if we use a module operator, but I think you have to work in your logical expression, I can't understand because I don´t know the context

there is a one solution for you:

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
  id          NUMBER,
  comm1       number,
  comm2       number,
  comm3       number,
  comm4        number GENERATED ALWAYS AS  ( mod ( 1 , ((comm1 - bitand(comm1, comm2) + comm2) - bitand((comm1 - bitand(comm1, comm2) + comm2),comm3)+comm3) ) ) VIRTUAL,
  CONSTRAINT employees_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```